# This is a constant in PHP?

Tags: php, class, syntax, constants

Use MyClass::class in PHP is a constant? I'm curious because the syntax is the same for access class constants.

PS: MyClass is just a example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean the `$className = MyClass::class;`

It's a [class constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php).